# How to automatically get returncode from Popen after terminating child process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, popen

I have a Python 3 question.  How do I automatically get the returncode from a Popen object after the child process terminates?

In short, I need an application to wait, but not be unresponsive (if possible), until the child process ends, and then automatically call a function based on the returncode.

Comment: Are you using a GUI framework? If so, which one?

Comment: Actually, I'm not entirely sure how to answer that, since what I'm doing is writing a script for Blender (a 3D modeling application).  May I ask why you're asking? :D

Comment: In a GUI, to stay responsive you need to keep processing incoming events (mouse clicks, etc), and the way to do that depends on your GUI.

Comment: A quick look at blender's documentation suggests there isn't a way to have a long running task while remaining responsive. So if it isn't responsive enough with @Ryan's solution, then you're stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

The following "might" be what you're looking for, but it's possible I don't quite understand what you want.

```
import subprocess
child = subprocess.Popen(do_something_here)
streamdata = child.communicate()[0]
rc = child.returncode
```

You can find more information about this here:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode

If I misunderstood your question, please let me know and I'll try and help you more with this.

Comment: I think you mean `child.returncode` instead of `return.code`.

Comment: Huh. Yep, that works. I don't completely understand WHY, though. By calling communicate(), it waits for the process to end before assigning child.returncode?

Comment: @swingsoneto, that's exactly what happens. `communicate()` waits for the process to exit before returning.

Comment: @SethMMorton - yes, my apologies. I've fixed the typo.